# OpenCV won't install to python

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, build

I am trying to install OpenCV 4.5.5 with CUDA support. I installed the source from their GitHub and the additional OpenCV contrib and built it with CMAKE. I checked BUILD_opencv_python3 when it was done configuring and generating it showed that it had detected python3 and had installed cv2 in site-packages.

[image: CMAKE says it detects python and installs CV2]

But cv2 isn't in the site-packages.

[image: CV2 not included in site-packages]

So it doesn't load in python. But it does give an interesting error
[image: DLL not loaded]

What should I do?

I already tried doing a fresh build with CMAKE but it didn't work.

After building OpenCV it generates a PYD file in the lib folder. I don't know if that is helpful or not.

Thanks

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed a step in the process.

- "Configure" step in `cmake-gui`, investigates the environment (various paths, e.g. where python wants packages to go) and prepares information for the build
- "Generate" step in `cmake-gui`, generates the actual build files (VS Solution)
- open the `.sln` in Visual Studio
- build the `ALL_BUILD` target
- build the `INSTALL` target, and **this installs** the files, also the python package

Comment: I just ran the INSTALL and it seemed to have worked. I did run the ALL_BUILD though.